# Designing how to add multiple items for a user in a database?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm relatively new into designing databases so this is my first project and I'm trying to understand better it's **structure**.

I need to create a SQLite database where there will be a simple **USERS** table with personal information such as *name, sex, age, etc*.

Then, each user will **Add** as many **Dog names** they want on a List.

I was considering to use more than 1 table, where every user will have it's own ID and it will be assigned with the other table, however I'm not sure how to do it without leaving the user with a limit of dogs.

How should I design it to support as many dogs as the user wants?

Comment: You do it by using a DOG table that *references* the USERS table. Read up about *foreign keys* - this is exactly the concept that allows you to represent unlimited relations between things.

Comment: Thank you Kilian. I'll do some research on this topic. But it looks that I'm on the right path, isn't it?

Comment: In addition to the above, what you are trying to create is called a "one to many" relationship.

Comment: This is one of the more common relationships, so try to understand the relationship well.  If you're not sure the relationship between two entites, ask yourself, "Does one X have many Y?"  followed by "Does one Y have many X?"  If the answer is Yes/No or No/Yes, you have one-to-many.  If it is No/No, then it is one to one, and if you have Yes/Yes, you have many-to-many.

Comment: Interesting. That's a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate table for dogs where you have the general information for each dog and then an owner field.

If you you don't like that, you can also have a separate table for dogs and then a relationship table that relates the dogs to their respective owners.